# How to query for records created X days ago given an array of days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to build a query that selects all records from a table that were created_at X days ago in a given array.

So, given [3, 8, 13, 21, 34, 50];

How can I find all records with MySQL that were created_at in 3, 8, 13, 21, 34, 50 days_ago?

Can MySQL figure out what 3 days ago was or do I need to pass in that specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question because MySQL does not support arrays.

If you have a *date* column, you can just do:

```
where created_at in (curdate() - interval 3 day, 
                     curdate() - interval 8 day,
                     . . .
                    )
```

If you have a date/time column, then you can adapt this as:

```
where date(created_at) in (curdate() - interval 3 day, 
                           curdate() - interval 8 day,
                           . . .
                          )
```

Alas, this prevents the use of indexes.  If that is an concern, then there are ways to rephrase this that are more index-friendly.